# Chromecast - SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

Only a small portion of my users are getting this error and I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I use `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(downloadService)` to test whether or not Play Services is available, and it always returns `SUCCESS`.  I setup the channel to connect to the Chromecast, and everything works fine up until the point where I try to use `RemoteMediaPlayer.load`.  The result is always `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` for some users, with `resolution: null`.  The `status.toString()` is `Failed to load: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}`.  I'm really not sure what I am supposed to with this or how to get rid of the error for my few users who are getting this.

I don't know what portion is related, so I am just posting my entire controller class:

```
public class ChromeCastController extends RemoteController {
private static final String TAG = ChromeCastController.class.getSimpleName();

private CastDevice castDevice;
private GoogleApiClient apiClient;
private ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks;
private ConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener;
private Cast.Listener castClientListener;

private boolean applicationStarted = false;
private boolean waitingForReconnect = false;
private boolean error = false;
private boolean ignoreNextPaused = false;
private String sessionId;

private FileProxy proxy;
private String rootLocation;
private RemoteMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private double gain = 0.5;

public ChromeCastController(DownloadService downloadService, CastDevice castDevice) {
    this.downloadService = downloadService;
    this.castDevice = castDevice;

    SharedPreferences prefs = Util.getPreferences(downloadService);
    rootLocation = prefs.getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY_CACHE_LOCATION, null);
}

@Override
public void create(boolean playing, int seconds) {
    downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.PREPARING);

    connectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks(playing, seconds);
    connectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener();
    castClientListener = new Cast.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationStatusChanged() {
            if (apiClient != null && apiClient.isConnected()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onApplicationStatusChanged: " + Cast.CastApi.getApplicationStatus(apiClient));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVolumeChanged() {
            if (apiClient != null && applicationStarted) {
                try {
                    gain = Cast.CastApi.getVolume(apiClient);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get volume");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
            shutdownInternal();
        }

    };

    Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions.builder(castDevice, castClientListener);
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(downloadService)
            .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
            .build();

    apiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void start() {
    if(error) {
        error = false;
        Log.w(TAG, "Attempting to restart song");
        startSong(downloadService.getCurrentPlaying(), true, 0);
        return;
    }

    try {
        mediaPlayer.play(apiClient);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start");
    }
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.pause(apiClient);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to pause");
    }
}

@Override
public void shutdown() {
    try {
        if(mediaPlayer != null && !error) {
            mediaPlayer.stop(apiClient);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to stop mediaPlayer", e);
    }

    try {
        if(apiClient != null) {
            Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(apiClient);
            Cast.CastApi.removeMessageReceivedCallbacks(apiClient, mediaPlayer.getNamespace());
            mediaPlayer = null;
            applicationStarted = false;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to shutdown application", e);
    }

    if(apiClient != null && apiClient.isConnected()) {
        apiClient.disconnect();
    }
    apiClient = null;

    if(proxy != null) {
        proxy.stop();
        proxy = null;
    }
}

private void shutdownInternal() {
    // This will call this.shutdown() indirectly
    downloadService.setRemoteEnabled(RemoteControlState.LOCAL, null);
}

@Override
public void updatePlaylist() {
    if(downloadService.getCurrentPlaying() == null) {
        startSong(null, false, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void changePosition(int seconds) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.seek(apiClient, seconds * 1000L);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FAiled to seek to " + seconds);
    }
}

@Override
public void changeTrack(int index, DownloadFile song) {
    startSong(song, true, 0);
}

@Override
public void setVolume(boolean up) {
    double delta = up ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    gain += delta;
    gain = Math.max(gain, 0.0);
    gain = Math.min(gain, 1.0);

    getVolumeToast().setVolume((float) gain);
    try {
        Cast.CastApi.setVolume(apiClient, gain);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to the volume");
    }
}

@Override
public int getRemotePosition() {
    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        return (int) (mediaPlayer.getApproximateStreamPosition() / 1000L);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getRemoteDuration() {
    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        return (int) (mediaPlayer.getStreamDuration() / 1000L);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void startSong(DownloadFile currentPlaying, boolean autoStart, int position) {
    if(currentPlaying == null) {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && !error) {
                mediaPlayer.stop(apiClient);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Just means it didn't need to be stopped
        }
        downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.IDLE);
        return;
    }
    downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.PREPARING);
    MusicDirectory.Entry song = currentPlaying.getSong();

    try {
        MusicService musicService = MusicServiceFactory.getMusicService(downloadService);
        String url;
        // Offline, use file proxy
        if(Util.isOffline(downloadService) || song.getId().indexOf(rootLocation) != -1) {
            if(proxy == null) {
                proxy = new FileProxy(downloadService);
                proxy.start();
            }

            url = proxy.getPublicAddress(song.getId());
        } else {
            if(proxy != null) {
                proxy.stop();
                proxy = null;
            }

            if(song.isVideo()) {
                url = musicService.getHlsUrl(song.getId(), currentPlaying.getBitRate(), downloadService);
            } else {
                url = musicService.getMusicUrl(downloadService, song, currentPlaying.getBitRate());
            }

            url = fixURLs(url);
        }

        // Setup song/video information
        MediaMetadata meta = new MediaMetadata(song.isVideo() ? MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE : MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
        meta.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, song.getTitle());
        if(song.getTrack() != null) {
            meta.putInt(MediaMetadata.KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, song.getTrack());
        }
        if(!song.isVideo()) {
            meta.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST, song.getArtist());
            meta.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, song.getArtist());
            meta.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE, song.getAlbum());

            String coverArt = "";
            if(proxy == null) {
                coverArt = musicService.getCoverArtUrl(downloadService, song);
                coverArt = fixURLs(coverArt);
                meta.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(coverArt)));
            } else {
                File coverArtFile = FileUtil.getAlbumArtFile(downloadService, song);
                if(coverArtFile != null && coverArtFile.exists()) {
                    coverArt = proxy.getPublicAddress(coverArtFile.getPath());
                    meta.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(coverArt)));
                }
            }
        }

        String contentType;
        if(song.isVideo()) {
            contentType = "application/x-mpegURL";
        }
        else if(song.getTranscodedContentType() != null) {
            contentType = song.getTranscodedContentType();
        } else if(song.getContentType() != null) {
            contentType = song.getContentType();
        } else {
            contentType = "audio/mpeg";
        }

        // Load it into a MediaInfo wrapper
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(url)
            .setContentType(contentType)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(meta)
            .build();

        if(autoStart) {
            ignoreNextPaused = true;
        }

        mediaPlayer.load(apiClient, mediaInfo, autoStart, position * 1000L).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // Handled in other handler
                } else if(result.getStatus().getStatusCode() != ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load: " + result.getStatus().toString());
                    failedLoad();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem occurred with media during loading", e);
        failedLoad();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem opening media during loading", e);
        failedLoad();
    }
}

private String fixURLs(String url) {
    // Only change to internal when using https
    if(url.indexOf("https") != -1) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = Util.getPreferences(downloadService);
        int instance = prefs.getInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY_SERVER_INSTANCE, 1);
        String externalUrl = prefs.getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY_SERVER_URL + instance, null);
        String internalUrl = prefs.getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY_SERVER_INTERNAL_URL + instance, null);
        url = url.replace(internalUrl, externalUrl);
    }

    //  Use separate profile for Chromecast so users can do ogg on phone, mp3 for CC
    return url.replace(Constants.REST_CLIENT_ID, Constants.CHROMECAST_CLIENT_ID);
}

private void failedLoad() {
    Util.toast(downloadService, downloadService.getResources().getString(R.string.download_failed_to_load));
    downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.STOPPED);
    error = true;
}


private class ConnectionCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private boolean isPlaying;
    private int position;
    private ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult> resultCallback;

    ConnectionCallbacks(boolean isPlaying, int position) {
        this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
        this.position = position;

        resultCallback = new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                Status status = result.getStatus();
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    ApplicationMetadata applicationMetadata = result.getApplicationMetadata();
                    sessionId = result.getSessionId();
                    String applicationStatus = result.getApplicationStatus();
                    boolean wasLaunched = result.getWasLaunched();

                    applicationStarted = true;
                    setupChannel();
                } else {
                    shutdownInternal();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (waitingForReconnect) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Reconnecting");
            reconnectApplication();
        } else {
            launchApplication();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        isPlaying = downloadService.getPlayerState() == PlayerState.STARTED;
        position = getRemotePosition();
        waitingForReconnect = true;
    }

    void launchApplication() {
        try {
            Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(apiClient, CastCompat.APPLICATION_ID, false).setResultCallback(resultCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to launch application", e);
        }
    }
    void reconnectApplication() {
        try {
            Cast.CastApi.joinApplication(apiClient, CastCompat.APPLICATION_ID, sessionId).setResultCallback(resultCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to reconnect application", e);
        }
    }
    void setupChannel() {
        if(!waitingForReconnect) {
            mediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusUpdated() {
                    MediaStatus mediaStatus = mediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
                    if (mediaStatus == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    switch (mediaStatus.getPlayerState()) {
                        case MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING:
                            if (ignoreNextPaused) {
                                ignoreNextPaused = false;
                            }
                            downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.STARTED);
                            break;
                        case MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PAUSED:
                            if (!ignoreNextPaused) {
                                downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.PAUSED);
                            }
                            break;
                        case MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_BUFFERING:
                            downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.PREPARING);
                            break;
                        case MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_IDLE:
                            if (mediaStatus.getIdleReason() == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED) {
                                downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.COMPLETED);
                                downloadService.onSongCompleted();
                            } else if (mediaStatus.getIdleReason() == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_INTERRUPTED) {
                                if (downloadService.getPlayerState() != PlayerState.PREPARING) {
                                    downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.PREPARING);
                                }
                            } else if (mediaStatus.getIdleReason() == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_ERROR) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Idle due to unknown error");
                                downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.COMPLETED);
                                downloadService.next();
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Idle reason: " + mediaStatus.getIdleReason());
                                downloadService.setPlayerState(PlayerState.IDLE);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        try {
            Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(apiClient, mediaPlayer.getNamespace(), mediaPlayer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while creating channel", e);
        }

        if(!waitingForReconnect) {
            DownloadFile currentPlaying = downloadService.getCurrentPlaying();
            startSong(currentPlaying, isPlaying, position);
        }
        if(waitingForReconnect) {
            waitingForReconnect = false;
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectionFailedListener implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        shutdownInternal();
    }
}
```

}

Edit for logs:

```
03-28 19:04:49.757    6305-6305/github.daneren2005.dsub I/ChromeCastController﹕ onApplicationStatusChanged: Chromecast Home Screen
03-28 19:04:52.280    6305-6305/github.daneren2005.dsub I/ChromeCastController﹕ onApplicationStatusChanged: null
03-28 19:04:54.162    6305-6305/github.daneren2005.dsub I/ChromeCastController﹕ onApplicationStatusChanged: Ready To Cast
03-28 19:05:05.194    6305-6305/github.daneren2005.dsub E/ChromeCastController﹕ Failed to load: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to using a Self Signed Certificate.  I didn't realize the issue on my old phone because I had changed hosts and bought a normal certificate after switching phones.  It would be nice if the SDK would through a useful error though.  The one thrown makes you think that it is a problem with connecting to the Play Services SDK, and not a problem with the actual URL being used.

Comment: what certificate are you referring to?

Comment: My app allows people to use their own Subsonic server, which can be http or https.  People using http servers, or https with a valid certificate are able to use Chromecast just fine.  Everyone who has their server setup with a self-signed certificate gets that error.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you are getting such status code at that time. What comes to mind is that the user may have not logged into his/her gmail account or something along those lines. Do you have the log file for us to take a look at to see if we can get more from the context? Also, to be sure, such user sees the application launched on the TV and only when it comes to loading a media that error is thrown?

Comment: Added the logs.  Yes, it displays the splash screen just fine, it just refuses to actually load anything.  I have one device I can reproduce the issue on, it is definitely logged into Gmail and everything appears to be fine on it except it doesn't have a SIM card in.

Comment: We need more log than that, potentially the whole session to see what is happening, with debug log turned on for Play services. Since log can be large, feel free to open an issue and attach that there.

Comment: I appended a full log at https://gist.github.com/daneren2005/c1cd23a8107f3730290c.  I can't see anything special going on there though.  I tried turning on debugging with .setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true), but I can't tell that it actually changed anything.  Is there something special I need to do?  If you would rather continue this discussion in a Chromecast issue that is fine with me.

Comment: So you can reproduce this yourself? If so, can you try running one of our Android samples and see if that runs for you.

Comment: I can't build the samples since Gradle just errors out on me no matter what I do.

Comment: what is the error? make sure you clone the CCL library with a name "CastCompanionLibrary" (i.e. without "-android" and have CastVideos and CCL as sibling projects, then you shouldn't see any error.

Comment: Yes, I have both CastCompanionLibrary and CastVideos cloned in the same folder, but I still get a `Bad pathname` error that is extremely vauge

Comment: Nm, I could never the library to work, but I did figure out the issue.